# Why getting me error in wordpress theme 'scheme.less' wasn't found (406) ?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

FileError: 'http://localhost:18550/wp-content/themes/onetone/css/scheme.less?ver=1.9.3' wasn't found (406)

in scheme.less?ver=1.9.3

please give me any suggestions i have downloaded WordPress OneTone Theme

Comment: do you have this file less.min.js: in theme?

Comment: A 406 error is a security mod from the apache server, there is 2 ways to stop these errors ( https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-wordpress-not-acceptable-error-406/ )  with the help of htaccess  You can also look how use less files in WordPress https://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/using-less-with-wordpress/.